# How to select nonextended columns?

Tags: acumatica

I have the following code in my BLC:

```
PXResultset<ARInvoice> previous = PXSelect<ARInvoice,
                                        Where<ARInvoice.projectID, Equal<Required<Contract.contractID>>,
                                        And<ARInvoice.createdDateTime, Less<Required<ARInvoice.createdDateTime>>,
                                            And<ARInvoice.customerID, Equal<Required<Contract.customerID>>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<ARInvoice.createdDateTime>>>.Select(this, contract.ContractID, invoice.CreatedDateTime, contract.CustomerID);
```

I have extended it to have additional column: "isInterestPenalty".

I would like to query it such that it only selects all non-interestPenalty.
Something like:

```
 ...And<ARInvoice.isInterestPenalty<Equal<Argument<bool>>>>>
    .Select(..., false)
```

I don't know how or can't seem to find in Acumatica T300 or how to search it in Acumatica API framework.

Answer (score 0):

In BQL expressions, you have to refer to the custom field by its BQL name in the extension class.

In you case BQL query should be composed as follows:

```
… And< ARInvoiceTableExtension.isInterestPenalty<Equal<Argument<bool>>>>>
.Select(…, false)
```

For more information on how to access extension objects from code, please refer to Help -> Customization:

[image]